# find.exe": missing argument to `-exec'

Tags: git, powershell

I use Windoes 7; Windows PowerShell; posh~git.

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec c:/unix2dos/bin/unix2dos '{}' +. \;

E:\TESSnip_Git\tesvsnip [tag-v4.3.0 +4 ~0 -0 | +0 ~308 -0]> find . -type f -name
 '*.php' -exec c:/unix2dos/bin/unix2dos '{}' +. \;
"C:/Users/DanoPDX/AppData/Local/GitHub/PortableGit_054f2e797ebafd44a30203088cd3d
58663c627ef/bin/find.exe": missing argument to `-exec'
E:\TESSnip_Git\tesvsnip [tag-v4.3.0 +4 ~0 -0 | +0 ~308 -0]>
```

That line does not work for Windows 7 and returns the error.  Also if I have 'unix2dos' in my path why can't I use it without specifying the exact path to it?

Comment: Did you try with `/c/unix2dos/bin/unix2dos` ? Did you try with _pure git bash_ ?

Comment: If I try "$ find . -type f -name '*.cs' -exec unix2dos '{}' +." gtom GitBash I get this; "find: missing argument to `-exec'"

Comment: If I try `find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec c:/unix2dos/bin/unix2dos '{}' +. \;` then I get this; unix2dos: converting file ./ObjectControls/RecordEditor.Designer.cs to DOS format ... unix2dos: Skipping +., not a regular file.

Comment: In git Bash you write paths as in `/c/...` not `c:/...` - glad you found it though

Comment: `find . -type f -name '*.cs' -exec /c/unix2dos/bin/unix2dos '{}' +.` that gives me the error: `find: missing argument to `-exec'`

Comment: `find . -type f -name '*.cs' -exec c:/unix2dos/bin/unix2dos '{}' +. \;` that gives me the error; `unix2dos: converting file ./ObjectControls/RecordEditor.Designer.cs to DOS format ... unix2dos: Skipping +., not a regular file.`

Comment: I got that line from [this link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22604/how-to-bulk-convert-all-the-file-in-a-file-system-branch-between-unix-and-window) and have been trying to figure it out.  I really appreciate your answers and I am happy to show what I have attempted to try and figure out how to do this from GitBash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure Powershell Answer:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter '*.php' | 
    Foreach-Object {
        & 'c:/unix2dos/bin/unix2dos' $_.FullName <# other unix2dos argshere #> 
    }
```

Or, the shorter way:

```
gci -rec -file -filter *.php  | % { c:\unix2dos\bin\unix2dos $_.FullName <# other args #> }
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I am so glad to finally have a way to do this.  I had made a windows Batch file with the list of files in it and then ran the batch file.  I really appreciate the answer.

Comment: +∞, if I could. Having PowerShell at your disposal and still trying to hack-job your way through with some of the most arcane Unix tools (`find` is an abomination, despite it being pretty good at what it does) is a weird way to approach problems.

Comment: I had to find this solution because I could not make Commits to my own repo that I am converting from SVN to Git.  If I copied files from the SVN repo to the Git folder and tried to make a commit, it will tell me that it can't because the line endings would change.  So I searched and the original link suggested find.  So when in Rome...  If I had my way there would be a GUI and I would never need a command line.

Answer (score 4):

I did some more searching for [GitBash command lines](http://ss64.com/bash/find.html#examples) and found out that the `'{}'` is the current file that find is using.  The `+.` is supposed to mean that the current directory should be included for the exec command.  However, it does not seem to work with GitBash for windows.

So I have found two options

1. What Eris suggested above
2. The following command line with GitBash for Windows

`find . -type f -name '<file-name>' -exec <path for unix2dos> '{}' \;`

Examples using GitBash:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec /c/unix2dos/bin/unix2dos '{}' \;
find . -type f -name '*.cs' -exec /c/unix2dos/bin/unix2dos '{}' \;
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec /c/unix2dos/bin/unix2dos '{}' \;
```

Note:

The above example shows a path to /c/unix2dos/bin/unix2dos because that's where I put it.  Having `c:\unix2dos\bin` in your Windows Path statement will not work with GitBash.